# IMPRIMIR ARCHIVO TXT API C#

Tags: c#, api

Hola estoy teniendo problemas al imprimir un archivo gurdado enun acarpeta de mi servidor local, este lo imprimo usando una api que tiene definida`enter code here` la ruta del archivo "dejo codigo"

```
 Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C COPY /B C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zqr\BD\QR_final.txt \\Server\ZDesigner";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.Start();
            process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

Este codigo solo funciona de manera local y quisiera saber si existe otra forma de mandar a imprimir ya que el iis bloquea las peticiones de imprimir y ejecutar cmd.exe ya que no cuento con los permisos del administrador

Comment: ¿Si o si debes imprimir desde el servidor? Porque en web generalmente el que envia a imprimir es desde el browser del cliente que esta navegando. Por que esto de ejecutar impresion desde el servidor puede ocasionar problemas al accesar varios y por temas la administracion "cola de impresion" (y otros problemas con impresoras) . Por ejmplo podrias crear un pagina HTML o PDF para imprimir ese archivo desde el brower. ¿por que esto no es una alternativa? Asi entendemos el requerimiento

Answer (score 0):

Intenta darle permisos a la carpeta del proyecto alojado en IIS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de hecho tienen todos esos permisos habilitados, el archivo .txt se modificada cada que hace una peticion con la fecheactual y si tiene permisos de lectura y escritura, lo que me extrana es que no manda la opcion de imprimir

Comment: Entonces intenta poniendo process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
Para dar como ejecución de administrador.